# Measuring velocity of sprite that is using actions

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a sprite moving around my screen and I want to orient it's rotation based on it's velocity. Well I've given it a `physicsBody`, but calling `velocity.dx` or `dy` is giving me `0.00000`. I'm assuming this has to do with the fact that I am using `SKAction`s to move the sprite, not impulses or forces. How can I get the `dx` and`dy` information I need in my `update:` method?

Comment: Yup, nodes with physics should not be moved with move actions, doing so is in conflict with physics and negatively affects collision behavior (ie passing through collisions, stuttering). Use physics forces/impulses to move the node if you expect it to behave like a physics object, otherwise don't use physics and move it with actions.

Comment: I agree with LearnCocoa2D.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, it appears there is no way to do this. However, I came up with another way to do it, simply by computing the `x` and `y` differences in where my sprite was going to move and using the `atan2f` function.

I haven't had any difficulties with contacts/collisions being ignored like I was warned about.